# Why Istio Mixer use two deployments to do Telemetry collection and policy checking separately?

Tags: istio

After deploying istio, we can see two deployment based on Mixer: `istio-policy` and `istio-telemetry`. They have the same pod spec on container `mixer`:

```
containers:
- args:
  - --address
  - unix:///sock/mixer.socket
  - --configStoreURL=k8s://
  - --configDefaultNamespace=istio-system
  - --trace_zipkin_url=http://zipkin:9411/api/v1/spans
  image: anjia0532/istio-release.mixer:master-latest-daily
  imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
  livenessProbe:
    failureThreshold: 3
    httpGet:
      path: /version
      port: 9093
      scheme: HTTP
    initialDelaySeconds: 5
    periodSeconds: 5
    successThreshold: 1
    timeoutSeconds: 1
  name: mixer
  ports:
  - containerPort: 9093
    protocol: TCP
  - containerPort: 42422
    protocol: TCP
  resources:
    requests:
      cpu: 10m
```

I have two questions:

1. How can the mixer container know they should be responsible for telemetry collection or policies control? I guess they are differentiate by the different arguments of istio-proxy container?
2. Why not use the same deployment for both functions?

Answer (score 1):

I will share my understanding on this feature.
We can see that this separation was done in version `0.6` as written in [release notes](https://istio.io/about/notes/0.6/).

> Separate Check & Report Clusters. When configuring Envoy, it’s now
>   possible to use different clusters for Mixer instances that are used
>   for Mixer’s Check functionality from those used for Mixer’s Report
>   functionality. This may be useful in large deployments for better
>   scaling of Mixer instances.

Why is it important? The policy checks are performed before each request so this is where the latency may come from, thus we may have a need to scale the mixer-policy component. 
Whereas the telemetry report happens after the request, moreover the sidecar buffers the outgoing telemetry so the call to the mixer-telemetry are not so often.
Also the latency on telemetry data is not so critical as it won't affect UX of you application.

So in short, the main reason for this is scalability issues, specially for multicluster environment.